# Multiprocessing combinations inexplicably slowing down depending on how random input data was created and how repetitive it is

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, random

I wrote code in Python 2.7 to create unique combinations of lists of unique elements also using multiprocessing.

The input would be a list of lists that contain unique elements, e.g.:

```
[['z', 'u', 'w', 'f'], ['k', 'z', 'u', 'o', 'w'], ['z', 'u', 'w', 'f'], 
 ['a', 'k', 'u', 'w', 'x', 'z'], ['e', 'f', 'i', 'k', 'u', 'x', 'z'], ['u', 'f']]
```

The output of the first sublist then looks like this:

```
['f_u', 'f_w', 'f_z', 'u_w', 'u_z', 'w_z']
```

This is a reduced part of my full code (please ignore `LA0`), enough to show the problem:

```
import multiprocessing as mpr
import time
import numpy.random as nr
import itertools as it

def combineSets(L0):
    LT = list(it.combinations(sorted(L0),2))
    return ['_'.join(LT[i]) for i in range(len(LT))]

def multiproc(L0,nproc):
    pool = mpr.Pool(processes=nproc)
    LLX = pool.map(combineSets,L0)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return LLX

def main(L0,nproc=1):
    time0 = time.time()
    if nproc == 1:
        LX = []
        for ll in L0:
            LX.append(combineSets(ll))
    else:
        LX = multiproc(L0,nproc)
    print "Combining took "+str(time.time()-time0)+" s"
    return LX

def sampleData(lenSheet,lenList):
    nr.seed()
    choices = list('aeioukzwxfqpgbv')
    pChoices = [0.02,0.03,0.02,0.03,0.2,0.075,0.125,0.15,0.15,0.1,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02]
    L0 = [list(set([nr.choice(choices,p=pChoices) for _ in range(nr.randint(2,high=lenSheet+1))])) for _ in range(lenList)]
    L0 = (1000000/lenList)*L0
    print "lenList: "+str(lenList)
    return L0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lenSheet = 15
    lenList = 100
    L0 = sampleData(lenSheet,lenList)
    nproc = 1
    print "Cores: "+str(nproc)
    res = main(L0,nproc)
    nproc = 10
    print "Cores: "+str(nproc)
    res = main(L0,nproc)
```

- `combineSets()` creates the combinations, not the version I'm actually using but it yields the same result for this example.
- `multiproc()` does the whole multiprocessing stuff.
- `main()` of course is the main program.
- `sampleData()` creates a large dataset of random test data.

Now lets look at `sampleData()`.

The parameter `lenSheet` is the maximal length of one sublist with elements chosen from `choices`.

The variable `lenList` is the length of the randomly created unique list of lists.

The code `L0 = (1000000/lenList)*L0` then makes sure there are always 1000000 sublists. If e.g. I only create 100 unique ones then they will just be repeated a 10000 times, so data with low values of `lenList` will be highly repetitive.

Here I'm using `numpy.random.choice()` and because it doesn't do unique choices I also use `set()` on the result. This changes the random data though by overall decreasing the amount of sublists with higher numbers of elements and creating sublists of length 1 which are useless, but I didn't want the elements to be chosen by equal probabilities at first.

Then I tried a different simpler approach to create random data using this line instead:

```
import random as rd
L0 = [rd.sample(choices,nr.randint(2,high=lenSheet+1)) for _ in range(lenList)]
```

This code yields data whose lengths are distributed equally  from 2 to `lenSheet` if `lenList` is large enough.

Now keep in mind that the longer a sublist is the longer it takes to calculate all possible combinations and that time is strongly increasing with higher numbers.

Due to this I'm expecting the algorithm to work faster with the data created by using `numpy.random.choice()` since it has much less sublists with higher lengths.

Data is fully random, no fixed seed is used.

Here's what actually happens:

Lets first look at the calculations using `random.sample()`:

I'm increasing `lenList` from 100 to 1000000, meaning I go from highly repetitive data to a completely unique dataset, and do calculations each on 1 and on 10 cores. I'm using the print output though I know that it's not as accurate as `timeit`, but that doesn't really matter:

```
lenList: 100
Cores: 1
Combining took 11.5520000458 s
Cores: 10
Combining took 17.3930001259 s

lenList: 10000
Cores: 1
Combining took 12.1019999981 s
Cores: 10
Combining took 18.8040001392 s

lenList: 1000000
Cores: 1
Combining took 11.5900001526 s
Cores: 10
Combining took 18.5590000153 s
```

The overhead from `multiprocessing` is strong, but the ratio between single-processing and multi-processing is steady and not dependent on `lenList`, that is on how repetitive the data is.

Now with the random data using the `numpy.random.choice()`-random data:

```
lenList: 100
Cores: 1
Combining took 5.53099989891 s
Cores: 10
Combining took 8.14699983597 s

lenList: 10000
Cores: 1
Combining took 5.32299995422 s
Cores: 10
Combining took 9.90599989891 s

lenList: 20000
Cores: 1
Combining took 5.92899990082 s
Cores: 10
Combining took 14.0799999237 s

lenList: 50000
Cores: 1
Combining took 5.69400000572 s
Cores: 10
Combining took 28.9730000496 s

lenList: 100000
Cores: 1
Combining took 5.88800001144 s
Cores: 10
Combining took 50.2009999752 s

lenList: 1000000
Cores: 1
Combining took 5.75199985504 s
Cores: 10
Combining took 50.7860000134 s
```

As expected the single-processing is faster than with the other dataset since the data has less sublists of large lengths.

However the calculation time with `multiprocessing` goes up heavily between 10000 and 100000 and then stays at around 10 times as much as single-processing. This shows a sensitivity to the decreasing repetitiveness of the data.

Ten processes each working with a tenth of the data take ten times as long as a single process working with all the data.

Really the only difference between both cases is the way the random data was created, that is the distribution of the lengths of the sublists and that difference is such that with the `numpy.random.choice()`-data it should work faster which it also does, only not for random data with a higher degree of uniqueness and less repetition in the case of multiprocessing. Given that the single-process time stays the same the repetitiveness of the data has no impact on performance.

I have really no idea what's going on, can anyone give me hint on what might be causing this?

Do I have some really strange bug in my code?

Is multiprocessing sensitive to the different processes getting rather different loads of work?

EDIT 1: Simplified the code, the results are pretty much the same.

EDIT 2: I ran the last case with 2 cores instead of 10, the time was `54.34 s`, so the number of cores doesn't seem to matter.

EDIT 3: More results, after simplifying the code I tried the same calculations with 2 cores instead of 10, the problems remains the same:

Calculations with the `random.sample()` data:

```
lenList: 100
Cores: 1
Combining took 10.8669998646 s
Cores: 2
Combining took 17.8090000153 s

lenList: 10000
Cores: 1
Combining took 10.9370000362 s
Cores: 2
Combining took 18.8830001354 s

lenList: 1000000
Cores: 1
Combining took 11.3680000305 s
Cores: 2
Combining took 19.1840000153 s
```

Calculations with the `numpy.random.choice()` data:

```
lenList: 100
Cores: 1
Combining took 5.1210000515 s
Cores: 2
Combining took 11.4690001011 s

lenList: 10000
Cores: 1
Combining took 5.06900000572 s
Cores: 2
Combining took 13.2760000229 s

lenList: 1000000
Cores: 1
Combining took 4.63499999046 s
Cores: 2
Combining took 54.754999876 s
```

EDIT 4:

I did some profiling of the `multiproc()` function using `cProfile` with the `numpy.random.choice()`-runs.

The main difference seems to lie in the following lines.

For `lenList = 100`:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
35   11.386    0.325   11.386    0.325 {method 'acquire' of 'thread.lock' objects}
```

For `lenList = 1000000`:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
35   49.839    1.424   49.839    1.424 {method 'acquire' of 'thread.lock' objects}
```

I'm not knowledgeable about locking, so I might have to read up on that for now. Maybe someone can enlighten me here.

Comment: How many processor cores does your computer *have*?

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. You have a lot of documentation, and more code than should be necessary to recreate the problem.

Comment: @aryamccarthy: It has 12 cores. And I will try to simplify it.

Comment: @roganjosh: I thought I had to do chunking manually, thanks for telling me. Running the code without chunking now.

Comment: @roganjosh: Are you testing the simplified code now?

Comment: @roganjosh: Did you also add my second edit? At first I thought the chunking also applies to the results so I tried to recombine the results, I removed that, and now for me `res` has always the same length.

Comment: Ok, the second edit does show the same length of output.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway, I will try to profile the process now.

Comment: Bear in mind that processes are expensive to create and only worthwhile if you're doing a significant amount of work in each process.

Comment: I'm not quite following, but please go on. Just, can it even be a general issue if it only appears for a certain dataset?

Comment: Please take note of my last edit.

Comment: Code was still faulty, corrected function `combineSets()`.